# DIV Hidden element space adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a strange problem.

I am using toggle to show and hide content of a page. I change the visibility of the div element based on an onclick event in javascript and it works fine.

My problem is even though some content is hidden before onclick, space is allocated in the page and once click event occurs text appears in the space. If we click again the text disappears.

I want the space also to disappear otherwise it looks awkward. I will attached the image for further reference. Only javascript,css and php no jquery solutions please.
[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Thank you for the edits.Sorry for confusing description.I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using CSS `display: none` rather than `visibility: hidden` if that is what you are doing.  `visibility: hidden` just makes an element invisible, but holds its place in the document, whereas `display: none` removes the item from the document flow altogether.

Comment: @user1633170 Glad to help.  I find it odd that you ran across the `visibility` property before discovering `display` as `display` is probably used 1000x more frequently by developers.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
display: none;
```

instead of

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to determine your error without seeing your code but here is a good example to start off with.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>
```